# How do I pass a variable to a custom Django template loader?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have templates in a dictionary and I'd like my template loader to fetch them. But since it's instantiated by the Django code I can't pass it the dictionary at that point.

What is the proper way to pass a variable to a template loader? (The dictionary is built dynamically, so I can't use the Django settings file.)

My loader code, I can't use `dictionary` yet:

```
class Loader(BaseLoader):
    is_usable = True

    def load_template_source(self, template_name, template_dirs=None):
        if template_name in dictionary:
            return (dictionary[template_name],template_name)
        raise TemplateDoesNotExist("Could not find template '%s'." % template_name)

    load_template_source.is_usable = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem? This should work.

Just define `dictionary` somewhere..

```
dictionary = {'template_name' : 'template content'}

class Loader(BaseLoader):
    is_usable = True

    def load_template_source(self, template_name, template_dirs=None):
        if template_name in dictionary:
            return (dictionary[template_name],template_name)
        raise TemplateDoesNotExist("Could not find template '%s'." % template_name)
```

If it needs to be dynamic, throw in a function that populates `dictionary`.

```
class Loader(BaseLoader):
    is_usable = True

    def load_template_source(self, template_name, template_dirs=None):
        if template_name in self.get_dictionary():
            return (dictionary[template_name],template_name)
        raise TemplateDoesNotExist("Could not find template '%s'." % template_name)

    def get_dictionary(self):
         dynamic = {}
         # magically dynamically populate the dictionary
         return dynamic
```

Comment: I had to populate the dictionary in another function and I forgot to add `global dictionary` before assigning to it. Thanks for the help.